# SQL Error : Arithmetic overflow error converting Numeric to Numeric - with Numeric(20,20) column type

Tags: sql-server

I am at my wits end on this one. I have rebuilt the table I am using several times. ALL of my columns that contain any number is currently set to `numeric(20,20)` - yes I know it is ridiculous.

I did try using `Decimal(10,10)` which is more realistic to the data I am getting but i cannot get past this error.

I am trying to insert values that may be a whole/decimal/negative value.

The import I am testing with is this:

```
INSERT INTO table1.table ([station], [site], [station_num], [line_volt],[redux_volt])
VALUES ('station1', 'bullrush', 23, 1.322455, 0.234567)
```

It results in an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to datatype numeric

Is there anything else that can cause this error BESIDES too many numbers in a numeric field?

Comment: The *only* number out of those that will fit in a `decimal(10,10)` or `numeric(20,20)` out of those values is `0.234567`. Both are saying that you have a scale the same size as your precision, which means that the can't store any values >= 1 or <= -1, as that would require at least 1 level of precision that isn't allocated to the scale.

Comment: I guess you've mis-interpreted how the `numeric` type is defined, in SQL Server. The `numeric(20,20)` means: a number with a **total** of 20 digits - thereof **20** digits **after** the decimal point. If you assumed this meant 20 digits before and 20 digits after the decimal point, you're (a) mistaken, and should (b) be using `numeric(40,20)` instead (which doesn't work, since the max. "scale" - the first number - can only be 38 at most). Read all about it in the **official MS docs**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I thought i understood, but based on the comments i have received on this appearently i didn't..

i ended up with numeric(10,6) since the data will never be more than 99.999999 that seemed to make everything happy.  Thanks.

Comment: `NUMERIC(20, 20)` of course will error out when you try to insert `0.234567`.  You can see there's a number (0) before comma.